# Why is a valid SSL certificate required for SSL-Strip?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

From what understand, SSL-Strip sits between the target user and the server, establishing a HTTPS connection between itself and the server, and an unsecured, plain old HTTP channel between itself and the target user.

What confuses me is, [in a video demo of the tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNhyjPxuy5w), one of the prerequisites was an SSL certificate.

Why is the certificate required? Can't the "computer proxy acting as a fake user" send the plaintext back to the user without one? In fact, it seems the only reason a signed SSL certificate would be required would be if the middle-man sent back HTTPS encrypted data back to the user.

Comment: Watch this video from the creator of sslstrip so you can understand how it works. [Def Con 17 - More Tricks For Defeating SSL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dhSN9aEljg). It explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

SSLStrip can work of one of two ways:

> It will transparently hijack HTTP traffic on a network, watch for HTTPS links and redirects, then map those links into either look-alike HTTP links or homograph-similar HTTPS links.

The video is talking about the latter.  So you can still use HTTPS, but try to fool the victim into going to https://www.gmail.attacker.com.  Where the attacker owns a valid SSL cert for *.attacker.com.  A valid SSL cert isn't required if you're simply replacing https links with http links.  i.e. https://www.gmail.com with http://www.gmail.com

http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/